# sendmail lda parameter for full recipients address

Tags: sendmail, procmail, dovecot, sieve-language

Using this:

```
define('LOCAL_MAILER_ARGS', 'procmail -t -Yo -a $h -d $u')
```

in my sendmail mc gives a procmail LOGNAME like

```
user
```

instead of

```
user@domain.com
```

using

```
define('LOCAL_MAILER_ARGS', 'procmail -t -Yo -a $h -d $u@$h')
```

gives then

```
user@localhostname
```

My problem is, we have email users in the form 'user@domain.tld' and not 'user' - thus procmail can't find e.g. mail directories with just the user address portion 'user'. 
How can one provide procmail the full recipients address from sendmails lda call?

EDIT:

I'll try it to be more clear, to see the reason.

My 'virtual' recipients are a) no system users and the have different domains in their address, all set with the use_cw_file feature. Local mailer is procmail AND dovecot (+sieve), which is finally handling the virtual users, too. Because dovecot is naming the domain by in addition to the user to handle e.g. admin@domain1.com and admin@domain2.com on the same host.

So I need sendmail to deliver the full address to the lda(stack) (procmail -> sieve -> dovecot).

Comment: Email user means OS account in your case, does not it?

Comment: you mean something like system user in /etc/passwd? No, just 'virtual' users for more than one domain. That's why no mapping is possible.

Comment: What's the role of Procmail here anyway? http://wiki2.dovecot.org/LDA/Sendmail suggests `dovecot-lda` instead, which somehow makes more sense in this context.

Comment: Procmail is used to filter as it is intended for, before it hands over to deliver. We check e.g. for user and domain whitelists, talking to a spamd etc.

Answer (score 1):

### Sendmail: procmail delivery for virtual domains

You may select procmail mailer with prcoamil script as argument in mailertable (procmail as local mailer is a different beast).

mailertable file:

```
# deliver messages to domain.tld 
# using etc/procmailrcs/domain.tld.rc procmail script
domain.tld  procmail:/etc/procmailrcs/domain.tld.rc
```

access (table) file:

```
to:domain.tls  RELAY
```

Comments:

1. procmail treats script in /etc/procmailrcs in special way (see `man procmail`)
2. mailertable IS NOT consulted for local email domains so access table entry is required to accept messages to the domain from everywhere.
   As root use `echo '$=w' | sendmail -bt` to get list of local email domains
3. You may use virtusertable with _VIRTUSER_STOP_ONE_LEVEL_RECURSION_ to list valid addresses in the domain and reject remaining
4. By default the scipt will be executed once per every recipient in the domain

Comment: +1 for a different but nice option.

Answer (score 0):

`$LOGNAME` is by definition a local user name.  I don't think that there is a way to override this (or that there should be one).

Comment: $LOGNAME is just the procmail side and procmail rules can handle full recipient addresses as dovecot can. So I guess there must be a way.